# hash map sorting by key

Tags: java, sorting, collections, hashmap, key

The following is my code by which I am printing unsorted key-value pairs.

I have 2 POJO classes and a main method.I have to sort my hashmap based on the **key**.I am required to do this in hashmap and cannot do in treemap or anything.Can anyone help?

**MAIN CLASS**

public class HashDemo {
public static void main(String args[]){

```
    EmployeeBean e1=new EmployeeBean(100,"selva",1000);
    EmployeeBean e2=new EmployeeBean(101,"siva",2000);
    EmployeeBean e3=new EmployeeBean(102,"silva",3000);

    DepartmentBean d1=new DepartmentBean(123);
    DepartmentBean d2=new DepartmentBean(456);
    DepartmentBean d3=new DepartmentBean(789);

    Map <DepartmentBean,EmployeeBean> map=new HashMap<DepartmentBean,EmployeeBean>();

    map.put(d1,e1);
    map.put(d2,e2);
    map.put(d3,e3);
    for(Map.Entry m:map.entrySet()){  
           System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue()); 
        }
```

}}

**EMPLOYEEBEAN**

public class EmployeeBean {

```
private int empid;
private String empName;

private int empSal;
public int getEmpid() {
    return empid;
}
public void setEmpid(int empid) {
    this.empid = empid;
}
public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}
public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}
public int getEmpSal() {
    return empSal;
}
public void setEmpSal(int empSal) {
    this.empSal = empSal;
}
public EmployeeBean(int empid, String empName, int empSal) {
    super();
    this.empid = empid;
    this.empName = empName;
    this.empSal = empSal;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "empid=" + empid + ", empName=" + empName + ", empSal=" + empSal + "";
}
```

}

**DEPARTMENTBEAN**

public class DepartmentBean {
    private int deptId;

```
public int getDeptId() {
    return deptId;
}
public void setDeptId(int deptId) {
    this.deptId = deptId;
}

public DepartmentBean(int deptId) {
    super();
    this.deptId = deptId;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "deptId=" + deptId + "";
}
}
```

Comment: Consider adding the programming language you use as a tag. Language tags are usually watched by many people, so you also get a better visibility of your question.

Comment: Thanks @ArneRecknagel .Done!